# Twilio Voice Call & Google Sheets/GAS Integration

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

I am running a GAS as a web app to pull variable text from a sheet and return it as XML for purposes of implementing a voice call utilizing Twilio.

I am getting a document parse failure because Twilio is "unable to parse the provided XML document."

The script I am using to implement this is available here:

https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/Twilio/MakePhoneCall

I am able to get as far as the call completing, but instead of my nice Twiml message, I get an application error.

The message text in Twilio's debugger says:

> Error on line 8 of document : The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag `</meta>`.

Any ideas why this is failing would be warmly and gratefully received.

Thanks!

Comment: The error sure seems specific. Have you debugged? Have you modified the code you link to **in any way**? If so, I strongly recommend you check your changes. Consider also that the Twilio API may have changed in the last 5 years, and so 5-year-old code may need modification.

Comment: The only code modifications I have made are the variables based on Twilio auth and sid. 

I have created my own message in the google sheet too. 

The twiml.html file that I am attempting to parse has checked out as valid XML and the Twiml is also good. 

I think the issue is with lines 64 to 79 of the script - specifically the creation of the XML from twiml.html. 

The debugger shows html output rather than the anticipated xml.